# Light in basement with no switch?

Tags: switch, basement

In my basement there is a light socket that is always on. We have checked every switch and there does not seem to be a switch attached. I followed the electrical line and it’s only connected to a two socket plug in the wall.

We took out the bulb for now but would be nice to figure out how to turn it off.

Is the wrong fixture installed?

Comment: Are you certain that light socket doesn't have a (possibly broken off) pull-string attached?

Comment: Not prudent (etc etc), but not unheard of for people to have an always hot light fixture where the 'switch' is them twisting the bulb a tiny bit.

Comment: Is the socket in the kind of location that might have been intended for a switch?

Comment: The cheapest easiest solution might be this: https://www.nostalgicbulbs.com/products/pull-chain-duplex-outlet-socket-html

Comment: I’m wondering if the pull string broke that is really interesting. Putting my son to bed then checking it out. Is it easy to install a pull string / chain.

Comment: Electricians trying to save any pennys, so In not finished basement they install socket with switch. Then you gonna finish the basement, you gonna change wiring.

Comment: These white ceramic fixtures are only about $3 - $5. If the plastic switch inside goes bad, that's it, replace the fixture. Put an LED in it and leave it on.

Comment: Yep pull chain totally broke off. Thanks all. Will need to replace fixture.

Comment: LED always on makes sense *except* if you sometimes need the room actually dark.

Comment: A  "Greenlite 9w/Omni/oc A19 E26"  may be a short term solution. It is a 9 watt LED with a built in motion detector. They are available in a 2 pack for about $10.

Comment: @brhans or Alan, please write that up as an answer so that it can get up votes (magical unicorn interwebz points!) and can get accepted. It's much more difficult for others to find answers in comments.

Answer (score 5):

If there hadn't been a switch or missing pull-string I would've probably used a **Wifi-LED and a wireless motion sensor**. You can set a timer on the motion sensor that determines how long the LED should remain on after no motion is detected. The LED can then also be controlled via your phone/tablet/PC.

With the right motion sensor, a *[Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/)* with *[Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/)* installed (and possibly *[NodeRED](https://nodered.org/)*) you can do even more crazy stuff. Not just with your lights, but many other devices (modern cars ([eg](https://www.mercedes-benz.com/en/vehicles/passenger-cars/a-class/).), tablets, Chrome Cast, TVs with internet, Spotify, Tile sensors, watering plants,...).

*(Or you could also control your lights/devices with Google Home, Apple's Home app or Samsung's SmartThings...)*

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this answer, but it's a bit like bringing in a wrecking ball where a tack hammer would do the job.

Comment: You can get standalone "wireless" bulbs. (I dont have any specific recommendations though as I am running Hue via Homeassistant myself)

Comment: they also have bulbs with motion detectors built in (GE), which even as an IoT nut I would recommend for low-frequency areas as there's nothing to go wrong with them and you're unlikely to need system integration.

Answer (score 5):

Check the light socket carefully for the remnants of a broken pull-string switch.
It's extremely unlikely that there's an always-on light in a basement (at least not on purpose anyway).
[image]
<sub>Example of a Leviton R50-08827-CW4 1-Piece Top Wired Lamp Holder with Pull Chain</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Fit a pull chain adaptor between the socket and the lamp.

[image]